# Hosts file to block a website

Tags: windows, hosts-file, block

I have seen a [blog](http://www.guidingtech.com/4868/edit-hosts-file-block-websites/) saying that we can block some websites using our hosts file. I have tried the same (shown below), but failed.
Entry added in host file as below:
127.0.0.1       www.google.com

I tried clearing the cache and tried it with a new website (which I have never been browsed before), but I get the website, making the blog content as false. Am I doing anything wrong here? Or is that something wrong with the blog content?

Comment: `but I get the website, making the blog content as false` - That statement makes no sense. Also, the entry you posted in your question will only resolve www.google.com to 127.0.0.1. It won't work for any other name. Did you put the FQDN of the other web site in your hosts file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this. Use a proper content filter, you'll be much happier in the long run than managing a mess of individual hosts files.

Comment: I have done this for testing purpose, not in real scenario. Just tested what I saw..

Comment: Questions asked on Server Fault should be about practical scenarios that you face in a real world professional environment. Refer it [ask] and [help] for more info.